# Setting up OpenGL - it won't work

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, glut, freeglut

I just bought a new laptop with windows 8 64bit and I am using Visual Studio 2012.
I did the usual procedure with installing a 3d party lib just as I installed them on my previous PCs:

1. Download freeglut, glew, glfw, glut, sdl
2. Copy headers into "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include"
3. Copy libs into "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib"
4. Copy dll's into "C:\Windows\SysWOW64"

Then I downloaded the project I was developing on my other PC (was developed under windows 8 32bit if that's of any importance) and it would'n compile. The compiler threw me the following linking error:

```
Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glDrawArrays@12  - about 50 of these 

Error 63 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4 - again about 50 of these
```

The project is working perfectly on my old PC.

I did try to make a simple new project: http://pastebin.com/GfEieL6f

Linked the following libraries (Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies)

```
opengl32.lib
glut32.lib
glu32.lib
```

And again it wouldn't compile, again the same linking errors:

```
Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glBegin@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl drawcube(void)" (?drawcube@@YAXXZ) P:\OpenGL_Setup\OpenGL_Setup\opengl_setup.obj

Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl drawcube(void)" (?drawcube@@YAXXZ) P:\OpenGL_Setup\OpenGL_Setup\opengl_setup.obj

Error 3 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClearColor@16 referenced in function _main P:\OpenGL_Setup\OpenGL_Setup\opengl_setup.obj

Error 4 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glColor3f@12 referenced in function "void __cdecl drawcube(void)" (?drawcube@@YAXXZ) P:\OpenGL_Setup\OpenGL_Setup\opengl_setup.obj

Error 5 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glEnd@0 referenced in function "void __cdecl drawcube(void)" (?drawcube@@YAXXZ) P:\OpenGL_Setup\OpenGL_Setup\opengl_setup.obj

Error 6 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glFlush@0 referenced in function "void __cdecl drawcube(void)" (?drawcube@@YAXXZ) P:\OpenGL_Setup\OpenGL_Setup\opengl_setup.obj

Error 7 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glLoadIdentity@0 referenced in function _main P:\OpenGL_Setup\OpenGL_Setup\opengl_setup.obj

Error 8 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glMatrixMode@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl drawcube(void)" (?drawcube@@YAXXZ) P:\OpenGL_Setup\OpenGL_Setup\opengl_setup.obj

Error 9 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glOrtho@48 referenced in function _main P:\OpenGL_Setup\OpenGL_Setup\opengl_setup.obj

Error 10 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glRotatef@16 referenced in function "void __cdecl drawcube(void)" (?drawcube@@YAXXZ) P:\OpenGL_Setup\OpenGL_Setup\opengl_setup.obj

Error 11 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glVertex3iv@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl drawcube(void)" (?drawcube@@YAXXZ) P:\OpenGL_Setup\OpenGL_Setup\opengl_setup.obj
```

I don't know if I am missing something, can you give me some ideas ?

PP: I managed to fix the simple program and run it, but I cannot run my old project. Maybe it's a problem because of the platform change ? How can I fix it?

Comment: shouldn't glut come first?

Comment: Yeah, try linking to glut first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't add files to the compiler `lib` directory.  Instead add another library search path to your project.
2. You probably downloaded library files that aren't compatible with VC++ 2012 and your project build settings.  In native code, you can't mix x86, x64, etc.  Static libraries need to match your project bitness, not your OS.  And Microsoft also changes/extends the library file format, as well as runtime library components used by the library, so you really should get a library file designed for your version of VC++.

Comment: In my case, I needed only to link against opengl32.lib.